# Is this hook really deprecated? ( manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column )

Tags: filters, hooks, deprecation

I've been adding some data to the columns of two taxonomies in a theme I'm working on. I've hit something that's got me confused though.
I'm using this hook `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column` but the [Adam Brown page on the hook](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/manage_%7B%24taxonomy%7D_custom_column) says it's no longer in use. When using the hook I get no errors, so can this be true? I can't seem to find a replacement either. How can I tell if my hook, or any other hook, is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column` is a dynamic hook, so until you are using a proper value for `$taxonomy` like `post_tag`, it would work perfectly.

Adam Brown page tells it as deprecated because it looks for exact match, while there is a change in the files so the current hook being used are `manage_{$this->screen->taxonomy}_custom_column` or `manage_{$screen->taxonomy}_custom_column` which accepts the same value whether it is `post_tag` or something else, and that's the reason you don't get error or warning.

Comment: I did think that the $this->screen->taxonomy property would be giving the same value as just passing $taxonomy. So, in a nut shell, everything is fine with this : )  

Thanks for taking a look into this for me.

Comment: Cheers Dan...!!